# PWM AC AC chopper for single-phase induction motor

Tags: induction-motor

[image]

I am trying to run a single-phase motor with the help of a PWM AC-AC chopper circuit. The circuit is attached and the experimental results are attached as well.

I have also tried a 220-240 V, 30 W fan and a 115 V, 60 Hz, 10 A drill machine motor. In both cases, the motor is drawing voltage and current but it's not running.

I do not have an output filter and I am getting lots of spikes on the output voltage and current when I try to turn on the motor. What should I do to turn the motor on with the help of this circuit?

[image]

Can someone help?

Comment: What is your PWM frequency? And the drill machine motor likely has a run capacitor which is going to interact badly with unfiltered PWM.

Comment: PWM frequency is 30Khz.

Comment: I would not be surprised if the parasitic capacitance of your motor's windings is eating it up. Can you cobble together an LC output filter? Be mindful of the current through the filter cap at the line frequency though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is a deadtime in which the snubber circuit of the mosfets are providing a path during the free wheeling of the motor. If we are going to put an LC filter, it will not short the capacitor?

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand. Can you post a schematic and perhaps some notes about the control scheme? The LC filter I suggest would look much like the lc filter on an ideal buck converter.

Comment: I couldnt find the option to load the schematic. But, as far as converter is concerned only, the schematic of my converter is same as this one on the following link.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Realized-PWM-AC-Chopper-with-Pulse-Transformer-Isolation_fig35_305711043

Comment: Please have a look only on the converter as I am performing an open loop experimentation by giving a duty cycle of 0.65

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140087/discussion-between-bryan-and-khan).